# problems communicating with driver from user mode

Tags: windows, kernel, drivers

I have a driver I've written, and I created a symbolic name to it. The symbolic name is ...

```
L"\\DosDevices\\somename"
```

... and when I try to access the device object using CreateFile from usermode, I always get error code 3 (Path not found).

I tried using CreateFile with the following paths ...

```
L"\\\\.\\somename"

L"\\Device\\somename"
```

... and it doesnt work: I always get error code 3

Does someone know why?

Comment: I'm probably wrong, but shouldn't it be CHAR, not WCHAR? (i.e. drop the L). Also, I'm fairly sure you'll need the slashes, hence: "\\\\.\\DosDevices\\somename".
Remember you'll always have you use two backslashes per backslash you actually want.

Comment: Has your driver *successfully* loaded, and during its initialization made those API calls which it needs to make in order to create/advertize a device name?

Answer (score 1):

Use [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657.aspx) and see whether the symbolic has been created successfully -- the link should show up under GLOBAL??. If not, your driver is faulty.

Btw. \\.\somename is correct.